# Detect MongoDB status

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We are currently storing performance and search stats from our app with a free `MongoDB` sandbox on `MongoLab`. They recently had an outage which in turn affected our app (there is no replica set on the free sandbox).

Is there anyway to check the status of a `MongoDB` connection quickly (without having to waiting for a timeout as this takes too long) before trying to insert or update any data?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Solid error handling requires to handle any type of error, not only foreseeable ones.. What's the problem with a timeout in a web app?

Comment: I'm basically trying to see if the server is alive. At present if I wait till connection times out it takes far too long and leaves the app unresponsive. I3arnon's answer below is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I see. Keep in mind that you can still timeout within any DB operation, even if a ping just a ms before succeeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "detect status" you want to see whether you can access the server then use `Ping`:

```
new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017").GetServer().Ping();
```

It throws an exception if the server cannot be reached.

Comment: This doesn't seem to exist in the latest version.

Comment: @AdamReed it doesn't. It's the old API. You can take a look at this though; http://stackoverflow.com/q/29459990/885318