# Check mongodb connecting string is valid or not in asp.net core

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core

How can I check MongoDB connecting string is valid or not using asp.net core.

```
var connectionString="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/local";
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var server = client.GetServer();
server.Ping();
server.Disconnect();
```

This code is not working

Comment: What do you mean by *not working*? Does it throw an exception or show incorrect results? And could you please specify what nuget package you are using

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoServer.State equivalent in the 2.0 driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29459990/mongoserver-state-equivalent-in-the-2-0-driver)

Comment: thanks for the response I need to know how to valid MongoDB connection string in the asp.net core